# Modify a csv file line by line

Tags: php, csv, file-io, highcharts

I have a big file that I want to modify every line in it.
I want to use PHP to do it quickly :

My file is CSV file ;

```
20010103,02,00,00,0.9496
20010103,03,00,00,0.9504
20010103,04,00,00,0.9499
```

I want to make it like this to be able to use it late with Highchart:

```
[Date.UTC(2001,01,03,02,00,00),0.9496],
[Date.UTC(2001,01,03,03,00,00),0.9504],
[Date.UTC(2001,01,03,04,00,00),0.9499],
```

How canI loop every line and make this modification ?

Comment: Open file for read, open another file for write; while not eof readfile, read from readfile, modify line, write to writefile; close both files

Comment: The numbers do not seem to match up. Where are you getting the `2013`? It does not appear in the CSV data...

Comment: I edited it, was mistake

Answer (score 11):

See the `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv` PHP functions. It will basically be something like:

```
if (($handle1 = fopen("input.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    if (($handle2 = fopen("output.csv", "w")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle1, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
           // Alter your data
           $data[0] = '...';

           // Write back to CSV format
           fputcsv($handle2, $data);
        }
        fclose($handle2);
    }
    fclose($handle1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    $filename = 'info.csv';
    $contents = file($filename);

    foreach($contents as $line) {
       $data = explode(",",$line);
       $val = "[Date.UTC(".substr($data[0],0,4).",".(substr($data[0],4,2)).",".substr($data[0],6,2).",".$data[1].",".$data[2].",".$data[3]."),".$data[4]."],";
    }
?>
```

Comment: what are you doing with the variable $val ?

Comment: does this code change the file ? or should I concat $val ($val=$val."[Date .... )then write it to another file ?