# How edit splitted values of a line in text file?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a text file where contains 1 line with this setting:

- 2222;3333

two values splitted by **`;`**.

How i can edit `"splitted[0]"` or `"splitted[1]"` and save the new values on file?

Below is what i have until now:

```
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("mytext.txt", "rw");
while (!feof($file_handle) )
{
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode("\n", $line_of_text);

    foreach ($parts as $str)
    {
        $str_parts = explode(';', $str); // Split string by ; into an array
        array_shift($str_parts); // Remove first element
        echo current($str_parts)."\n"; // echo current element and newline
        // Same as $str_parts[0]
    }
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Comment: You could read it as a CSV as in [Modify a csv file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910987/modify-a-csv-file-line-by-line), just change the delimiter in `fgetcsv($handle1, 1000, ",")` to be `";"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$file = '2222;3333'; // that is your file
$file = explode(';', $file); // This split your file with delimiter ";"

foreach ($file as $newFile) {
    // Do whatever you want
    var_dump($newFile);
}
```